# Location Access Deny from setting, checkSelfPermission returning always Granted (0) - Android

Tags: android, permissions, android-maps-v2

My app is using target-release version 22. I've mentioned `FINE_LOCATION` permission in `manifest` file.
When I'm running my app on android 6.0.1, it's working fine for my map-view where I'm showing current location.
But problem I'm getting when user "Deny" permission from app setting then app start crashing due to Permission-exception.

When I'm using below code

```
if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) 
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            }
```

But this code always returning `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`.
Can someone help to resolve this issue?

I've already gone through these links -
[Understanding the Android 6 permission method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211693)
[Request Permission at Runtime for Android Marshmallow 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150083)

Comment: what you used in Androidmainfest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's resolved by using PermissionChecker. PermissinChecker return status of Granted/Deny for even build version less than 23

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
    int permissionStatus = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(context, permission);
    if(permissionStatus != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 101);
        return false;
    }
}
```